# Conditional statement returns same result regardless of outcome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to manipulating the DOM to show who wins when playing Rock paper scissors game. I'm targeting a <p class="result" to do this.  But it doesn't matter what the result is, "it's a Draw" is only displayed. Please help!

On a side note, if any one has any suggestions on how to refactor this due to the multiple lines of "player wins", "Computer wins" code, then please let me know.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("button").length; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var playerChoice = (this.innerHTML);
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.querySelectorAll("button").length);
    var compChoice = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    document.querySelector(".player").innerHTML = playerChoice;
    document.querySelector(".computer").innerHTML = compChoice[random]

    if (playerChoice === "Rock" && compChoice === "Scissors") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Player Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && compChoice === "Paper") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Player Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && compChoice === "Rock") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Player Wins.";

    } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && compChoice === "Rock") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Computer Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && compChoice === "Scissors") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Computer Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Rock" && compChoice === "Paper") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Computer Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === compChoice) {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "It's a draw";
    }
     console.log(playerChoice);
  })
}
```

[https://ibb.co/44Z1vQ3](https://pasteboard.co/JYleKCe.png)

Comment: ```} else if (playerChoice = compChoice) {``` should be === not =

Comment: Thanks, i have amended this, but now the .innerHTML is not updating at all, in other words i am not getting a message saying who has won.

Comment: can you console.log the playerChoice and then edit your question to include that output as well as fixing the === error. My guess is that playerChoice isn't what you expected it to be. Remember that case sensitivity will matter

Comment: If i console.log(playerChoice) in the developer console i get:Uncaught ReferenceError: playerChoice is not defined at <anonymous>:1:13. But, if i add console.log(playerChoice) to the code inside my anonymous function, it will return the name of the button i am clicking on, and display as a string in the developer console. hope this helps. I have included an image of this at the bottom of the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you, this time).

Comment: Hi desertnaut, yes i have had trouble doing this, my apologies.

Comment: Welcome! Your HTML code would help as well. If you duplicate code, you should look into functions. For example:
`const computerWins = () => {
  // your stuff here
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandom's idea in the comments above to `console.log playerChoice` helped me realise a way to problem solve this by also console logging `compchoice` which returns an array, so i needed to encapsulate the `compChoice[random]` into a variable first shown below.

It is now all working as it should.

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("button").length; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    var playerChoice = (this.innerHTML);
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.querySelectorAll("button").length);
    var choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    var compChoice = choices[random]
    document.querySelector(".player").innerHTML = playerChoice;
    document.querySelector(".computer").innerHTML = compChoice;

    if (playerChoice === "Rock" && compChoice === "Scissors") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Player Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && compChoice === "Paper") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Player Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && compChoice === "Rock") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Player Wins.";

    } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && compChoice === "Rock") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Computer Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && compChoice === "Scissors") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Computer Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Rock" && compChoice === "Paper") {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "Computer Wins.";
    } else if (playerChoice === compChoice) {
      document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = "It's a draw";
    }
    console.log(playerChoice);
    console.log(compChoice);
  })


}
```